# End an event at midnight with Python and Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Guys, I'm working on a project on which Python 2.7 and Django 1.11.26 are used I need to make a change to a condition where events are discarded at the actual event starting time and make them discard at the end of the day (midnight)
this is the line of code concerned:

```
    show_card = lambda card: card.item.start_datetime >= timezone.now()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
from datetime import timedelta
show_card = lambda card: card.item.start_datetime >= timezone.now() < card.item.start_datetime.date() + timedelta(days=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your current line is discarding event if start datetime >= now, then this should discard if it is >= midnight today:

```
show_card = lambda card: card.item.start_datetime >= datetime.datetime.fromordinal((datetime.date.today()+datetime.timedelta(days=1)).toordinal())
```